# Magento upgrade 1.9.0 to 1.9.1 upgrade then blank page

Tags: magento-1.9.1

I'm new in magento, I see the following error message after the upgrade via ftp:

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup' not found in /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 234

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

It seems it has something to do with a missing class called "Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup" in......on line 234 so you need to type that class in the certain directory on line 234 which would be in "Setup.php". Once that's done you wont be getting the error message because the class is there or try upgrading again and see if they put the class in if not i don't know maybe complain to Magento?.

(if you dont know what a class is view this link if you wont to know: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php)

Comment: hi! thanks for your reply. SOLVED reuploading magento package.